# Insert into SQlite DB from SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-server-2014

I've successfully created a linked server between SQL Server 2014 (x64) and a SQLite database via ODBC.

I can select from the SQLite database with no problem.

```
select * 
from openquery(mp_test, 'select test1 from test2')
```

When I try to insert a record into to the database I get the following error :

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "mp_test" returned message
>   "unable to open database file (14)".
>
> Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "mp_test" could not
>   INSERT INTO table "[MSDASQL]".

All user has full control on the SQLite database file.

The code what I used for the insert :

```
insert openquery(mp_test, 'select test1 from test1 where 1=0') VALUES ('12')
```

Any idea?

Comment: `INSERT INTO mp_test.db_name.schema_name.test2(test1) VALUES ('12')`

Comment: Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "mp_test" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7312, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid use of schema or catalog for OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "mp_test". A four-part name was supplied, but the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or schema.

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO mp_test...test2(test1) VALUES ('12')` Should pick default DB and schema

Comment: Same error : OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "mp_test" returned message "unable to open database file (14)". :(