# Import data from SQL Server into SQLite?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I have data on my **local** SQL Server, which I want to import into my local SQLite database. I already created a linked server and got this query to work:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(DATASOURCE, 'SELECT * FROM TableName')
```

Similarly, I managed to import data from SQLite into my SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
INTO testTable
FROM OPENQUERY(DATASOURCE, 'SELECT * FROM TableName')
```

Now I want to do it the other way around (actually, I just want to insert one row of data here, but you get the idea), but I can't get it to work:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(DATASOURCE, 'INSERT INTO TableName (Comment) VALUES (''Test'')')
```

I keep getting this error:

> Cannot process the object "INSERT INTO TableName (Comment) VALUES (''Test'')". The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DATASOURCE" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

I guess I somehow don't have permission to insert stuff into the SQLite database, as the query is correct the way it is. How can I solve this error?

Comment: Have you tried the four part naming convention: `INSERT INTO DATASOURCE.database.schema.TableName(comment) values ('Test')`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid How would that work? I don't see a schema when I browse the database with DB Browser. Also what's the database name? The filename of the .db file? Didn't work btw, same error.

Comment: Try datasource...table

Comment: This article implies that should work, although it’s MySQL http://sql-articles.com/articles/dba/creating-linked-server-to-mysql-from-sql-server/

Comment: Before you try inserting try just selecting to make sure it's valid `SELECT * FROM Datasource...TableName`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Didn't work... here's the full script: `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DATASOURCE, 'SELECT * FROM DATASOURCE...TableName')`. All I get is this error: `OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MIROIRI" returned message "near ".": syntax error (1)".` along with this: `An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT * FROM DATASOURCE...TableName" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DATASOURCE".`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid When you said "datasource...table", did you actually mean that literally? Also tried just `SELECT * FROM DATASOURCE...TableName` btw, and I get this: `The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DATASOURCE" returned an invalid column definition for table "TableName".`

Comment: Does this ring any bells? https://www.sqlite.org/lang_naming.html  I’m not familiar with SQLLite. I know it’s always s challenge to get this four part name right. It definitely works for other DBMS. You may have to experiment.

Comment: Here’s an identical question with identical issue and same suggestions but no answer I’m afraid. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643296/insert-into-sqlite-db-from-sql-server-2014

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid With how little info there is, I'm not surprised that question wasn't answered. I hope mine will be different. And no, the link didn't help me understand this at all...

Comment: The SQLLite link mentions both a database and a schema. So maybe you’re missing them out. Or maybe not. I’m not familiar with SQLLite. You might need to use SSIS if you can’t get this working. But it’s worth persisting because then you can answer two questions.

Comment: Maybe try select * from datasource.main..table I know I’m just throwing stuff out here but that’s the only way to solve this stuff when there’s no online dock.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid F*** that, I give up. I'll just look for another workaround. Every time I get a possible solution, I just end up in another blockade. If I can figure this out (don't hold your breath...), I will write back here. And no, your suggestion didn't work either.

Comment: So is SSIS an option for you? There's no background on what your constraints are or what the purpose is. Linked server are really not a recommended way for data transfer anyway. If you want to batch data across to a, SSIS is probably a better option. Just to make absolutely clear: From my perspective this is an issue with the SQLLite ODBC driver and SQLLite documentation.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid All I want is to grab data from the SQL Server, in *SQL Server Management Studio*, and synchronize it with an SQLite database. I will look into SSIS, maybe it will fit my purposes.

Comment: SSIS is not _in SQL Server Management Studio_. I'm not sure if this is a real constraint or not.